# Why is my Cypress 12.12. configFile invalid with Angular 16?

Tags: angular, cypress, config, cypress-configuration

I am getting this error when running `npx cypress open`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    |                            ^
  5 |   e2e: {
  6 |     setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  7 |       // implement node event listeners here
  8 |     },
```

> TypeError: (0 , cypress_1.defineConfig) is not a function
> at Object. (/Users/id868720/magnolia-angular-cbu-role-selector-ng/cypress.config.ts:4:28)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
> at Module.m._compile (/Users/id868720/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.12.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:857:29)
> at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Object.require.extensions. [as .ts] (/Users/id868720/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.12.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:859:16)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
> at loadFile (/Users/id868720/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.12.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_require_async_child.js:89:14)
> at EventEmitter. (/Users/id868720/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.12.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_require_async_child.js:116:38)
> at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:12)
> at process. (/Users/id868720/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.12.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:33:22)
> at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)

with this config :

> Cypress package version: 12.12.0
> Cypress binary version: 12.12.0
> Electron version: 21.0.0
> Bundled Node version: 16.16.0
> node: v14.20.0

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "230623",
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "automation:report": "npx nyc report --reporter=text-summary",
    "build": "npm run build:all",
    "build:all": "ng build --extra-webpack-config ./webpack.extra.js --output-hashing=none --stats-json --project --single-bundle true && npm run process:bundle",
    "build:all:automation": "ng build --extra-webpack-config ./cypress/webpack.coverage.config.js --stats-json --output-hashing=none --single-bundle true && npm run process:bundle",
    "build:all:dev": "ng build --extra-webpack-config ./webpack.extra.js --output-hashing=none --configuration=dev --stats-json --project  --single-bundle true && npm run process:bundle",
    "build:automation": "npm run build:all:automation",
    "build:local": "ng build --extra-webpack-config ./webpack.extra.local.js --output-hashing=none --stats-json --project cbu-role-selector --single-bundle true --source-map && npm run process:bundle",
    "build:local:watch": "ng serve --configuration=local --project cbu-role-selector --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --open --single-bundle true",
    "build:watch": "ng build --watch --extra-webpack-config ./webpack.extra.local.js --output-hashing=none --project cbu-role-selector --single-bundle true",
    "build:watch:dev": "ng build --watch --extra-webpack-config ./webpack.extra.js --output-hashing=none --project cbu-role-selector --single-bundle true",
    "bundle:report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:all",
    "ci:compile": "npm run build:all && npm run process:package",
    "ci:lint": "ng lint",
    "ci:publish": "npm publish",
    "ci:sonar": "sonar-scanner",
    "ci:test": "npm run test",
    "compile": "npm run build:all",
    "compile:angular": "ngcc -s ./node_modules/@angular -p main",
    "cypress": "npx cypress open",
    "cypress:coverage": "npm run cypress:run && npm run automation:report",
    "cypress:install": "npm install cypress@12.12.0 --no-save --ignore-scripts",
    "cypress:run": "npx cypress run",
    "lint": "eslint projects/**/*.ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint projects/**/*.ts --fix",
    "local": "lite-server --baseDir=./elements -c ./config/node_red/bs-config.js",
    "node-red": "cd config/node_red && node ../../node_modules/node-red/red.js -v flows.json -s settings.js",
    "prepublishOnly": "node scripts/prepublishOnly.js",
    "process:bundle": "node ./scripts/process-bundle.js",
    "process:package": "sh ./scripts/package-version.sh",
    "process:watch": "node scripts/process-watch.js",
    "publish:nexus": "npm publish",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner",
    "sonar:automation": "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=-test-UI-local",
    "sort:package": "npx sort-package-json",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run node-red\" \"npm run local\" \"npm run process:watch\"",
    "stryker": "stryker run",
    "test": "jest --config=./jest.config-all.json"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run process:package && npm run lint:fix && npm run sort:package && git add .",
      "post-merge": "npm run process:package && npm run sort:package && git add ."
    }
  },
  "nyc": {
    "all": true,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "exclude": [
      "src/**",
      "cypress/**",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "coverage/**",
      "**/*.config.ts"
    ],
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "extension": [
      ".ts"
    ],
    "include": [
      "projects/**/*.component.ts",
      "projects/**/*.service.ts"
    ],
    "instrument": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@datorama/akita": "8.0.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.2.4",
    "@webcomponents/shadydom": "1.7.3",
    "file-saver": "1.3.8",
    "graphql": "15.8.0",
    "graphql-tag": "2.12.6",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.44",
    "localforage": "1.10.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "ngx-mask": "^14.0.3",
    "reselect": "2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "0.9.18",
    "tslib": "2.4.1",
    "url-polyfill": "1.1.12",
    "xstate": "4.6.7",
    "zone.js": "0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/elements": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "16.0.0",
    "@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "3.0.2",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "3.10.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "5.12.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ngdevtools": "3.0.2",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "1.0.1",
    "@proximus/pxs_angular_testing": "11.5.0",
    "@proximus/pxs-automation": "1.34.0",
    "@stryker-mutator/core": "6.1.2",
    "@stryker-mutator/html-reporter": "3.1.0",
    "@stryker-mutator/jest-runner": "6.1.2",
    "@stryker-mutator/typescript": "4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.119",
    "@types/node": "16.11.45",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.2",
    "apollo-server": "2.18.2",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "casual": "1.6.2",
    "concat": "1.0.3",
    "concurrently": "5.3.0",
    "copy": "0.3.2",
    "core-js": "2.6.9",
    "crypto-js": "4.1.1",
    "cypress": "^12.12.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "4.1.1",
    "cypress-shadow-dom": "1.4.1",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "39.3.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-snakecasejs": "2.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "8.0.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "2.0.1",
    "husky": "4.3.7",
    "jest": "29.5.0",
    "jest-create-mock-instance": "1.1.0",
    "jest-diff": "28.1.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.5.0",
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "2.4.21",
    "jest-mock": "28.1.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "13.1.0",
    "jest-silent-reporter": "0.5.0",
    "jest-when": "2.8.1",
    "jest-zone-patch": "0.0.10",
    "lint-staged": "10.5.4",
    "lite-server": "2.6.1",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "0.11.6",
    "ng-packagr": "16.0.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "16.0.0-next.7",
    "node-red": "1.0.5",
    "node-red-contrib-graphql": "0.2.5",
    "nodemon": "2.0.6",
    "nyc": "15.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "pretty-quick": "3.1.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "3.1.0",
    "sort-package-json": "1.48.1",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "9.3.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "webpack": "5.74.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.9.0"
  }
}
```

I have already tried:

- Delete node_module Folder
- Delete package-lock.json·
- Run npm cache clean --force Command Twice
- Run npm i·
- remove the cypress.config.ts file,
- delete the cypress folder,
- then reinstall Cypress,
- npm install cypress --save-dev
- npx cypress run --browser chrome

Comment: Is your first line of config `import defineConfig from 'cypress'` or `import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'`? The 2nd one is correct, the 1st can cause that error message. But the steps you took should have reinstated the correct line.

Comment: Why do you believe angular is relevant to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the  `cypress.config.ts`

From this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress' 
export default defineConfig({ ... )}
```

To this:

```
module.exports = { ... }
```

Comment: It helped in fact, but I see this answer like a workaround. In my case origin problem was invalid `tsconfig.json`. Once I fixed this file, everything started to work.

Answer (score -3):

You are likely encounter a formatting issue in your config file, please fix it the following way and add a `defineConfig` import:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
  // Cypress configuration options
});
```

Hope it will help. If no, please let me know

Comment: If you cannot provide a definitive answer you should use comments